# How can I perform for/loop with functions with jquery

Tags: jquery, loops, for-loop, css-selectors

How can I avoid repeating the following line of code using For / each in Jquery?

```
$('.slider__section:nth-child(1)').hover(function(){
  $('.slider__description').css("visibility", "hidden");
  $('.slider__section:nth-child(1) .slider__description').css("visibility", "visible");
  }, function(){
  $('.slider__description').css("visibility", "visible");
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slider__section">
    <div class="slider__description">1</div>
  <div>
  <div class="slider__section">
    <div class="slider__description">2</div>
  <div>
  <div class="slider__section">
    <div class="slider__description">3</div>
  <div>
  <div class="slider__section">
    <div class="slider__description">4</div>
  <div>
  <div class="slider__section">
    <div class="slider__description">5</div>
  <div>
  <div class="slider__section">
    <div class="slider__description">6</div>
  <div>
  <section class="fondo-slider"></section>
 </div>
```

I want to apply this to the 6 elements but I do not want to repeat this code
Try doing it like that but it does not work

```
function ocultarDescription() {
  $('.slider__description').css("visibility", "hidden");
  $('.slider__section:nth-child('+i+').slider__description').css("visibility", "visible");
}
function MostrarDescription() {
  $('.slider__description').css("visibility", "visible");
}
for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++) { 
  $('slider__section:nth-child('+i+')').hover(ocultarDescription, MostrarDescription);
}
```

I want to repeat it 6 times, besides, the nth-child will also change
I await your help. Thank you

Comment: Please show us your HTML code too. You might not need loop at all.

Comment: Rather then using `nth:child` you can use `jQuery.each`, You can find more details from below link.
 https://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: Please be more specific as to what you are trying to achieve - are you applying this to all `.slider_section-` or just some?  On the face of it you don't need a loop, just `$(".slider_section-pc").hover(...` if there are 5 elements.  If there are more than 5 and you only want the first 5, then you can use `$(".slider_section-pc:nth-child(-n+5)").hover(...`.  None of which warrant a "loop" given the information provided so far.

Comment: Also, 1 to <6 is 5 iterations, not 6.  You would normally go 0 to <6, or in this case, 1 to <=6 as `:nth-child` is 1-based

Comment: I have updated my code, please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery `each` can do that :

```
$('slider__section-pc').each(function(){
     $(this).hover( //do your stuff here);
})
```

if you want to put a function in the above stuff, you need a reference to `this` to be passed to those functions:

```
$('slider__section-pc').each(function(){
     var x=$(this);
     $(this).hover(ocultarDescription(x),MostrarDescription(x));
})
```

and then consume **X** in the target functions e.g.:

```
function ocultarDescription(x){
  $('.slider__description').css("visibility", "hidden");
  x.find(".slider__description').css("visibility", "visible");
}
```

Comment: I tried to do this but it does not work
function ocultarDescription() {
  $('.slider__description').css("visibility", "hidden");
}
function MostrarDescription() {
  $('.slider__description').css("visibility", "visible");
}

$('.slider__section-pc').each(function(){
     $(this).hover(ocultarDescription(), MostrarDescription());
});

Comment: Please vote up the answer if new details resolves your new question in the comments. @user7509372

Comment: @ Ali Sheikhpour I can not because he says I'm new

Answer (score 0):

Taking your original code, you can keep the methods inline, but use `this` instead of `i`:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {

  $('.slider__section:nth-child(i)').hover(function() {
    $('.slider__description').css("visibility", "hidden");
    $(this).find('.slider__description').css("visibility", "visible");
  }, function(){
    $('.slider__description').css("visibility", "visible");
  });
}
```

if you want this to apply to all `.slider__section` then there's no need for a loop:

```
$('.slider__section').hover(function() {
  $('.slider__description').css("visibility", "hidden");
  $(this).find('.slider__description').css("visibility", "visible");
}, function(){
  $('.slider__description').css("visibility", "visible");
});
```

if you want it to apply to just the first 6 elements and no more:

```
$('.slider__section:nth-child(-n+6)').hover(function() {
```

more info on `-n+6`: https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#nth-child-pseudo

Comment: I need to apply it to all the sections. The first code that you do not comment does not work, the message comes out: Do not make functions inside a loop. that's why I separated the functions. I have corrected my code, please watch it again.

Comment: Not sure I understand - the first code snippet above is commented with "use `this` instead of `i`" - look for `$(this).find(...`.  Whomever told you not to put functions inside a loop didn't explain to you the reasons why.  The main issue with using `i` inside the function inside the loop is that by the time it comes to execute the function (on an event handler) the `i` will have moved on.  Using `this` doesn't have that problem.